# Rewrite with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the what I'm trying to do. I've got these urls, Old form and New form

```
site.com/video.php -> site.com/video
site.com/index.php?cat_id=1 -> site.com/some-cat-name
```

Here is my htaccess file which is working only if one of the last two is commented.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond $1   !^(index\.php|img|js|css|admin|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^video$   /videos.php/$1 [L] 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /index.php/$1 [L]
```

if those two are active the server returns error 500

```
RewriteRule ^video$   /videos.php/$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /index.php/$1 [L]
```

my logic is if first is matched video in the url redirect to videos.php and forget for all under this line, but seems to be in other way. Can some one to explain how to have some predifined urls and all others to go on index.php, tnx in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 500 (Internal server error) because your rule is looping in this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /index.php/$1 [L]
```

To fix this rule have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1   !^(index\.php|img|js|css|admin|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^video$   /videos.php/$1 [L] 

# ignore existing files and directories from rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /index.php/$1 [L]
```